# Weird movement on bootstrap carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

So I built this "testimonial" slider on my website using bootstrap's carousel plugin but for some reason the movement seems clunky when it changes slides.. I'm not sure if it's my doing on the CSS because I styled on top of some of the elements and I don't really know too much of CSS..

Anyway, here's my code:
HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row testimonials">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3 class="text-center">Testimonials</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel slide" id="testimonial_slider" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#testimonial_slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#testimonial_slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#testimonial_slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="row item active">
                    <div class="col-md-6 testimonial">
                        <img src="my-image-url.jpg">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> The content</p>
                        <span>The Title</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 testimonial">
                        <img src="my-image-url.jpg">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> The content</p>
                        <span>The Title</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row item active">
                    <div class="col-md-6 testimonial">
                        <img src="my-image-url.jpg">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> The content</p>
                        <span>The Title</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 testimonial">
                        <img src="my-image-url.jpg">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> The content</p>
                        <span>The Title</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row item active">
                    <div class="col-md-6 testimonial">
                        <img src="my-image-url.jpg">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> The content</p>
                        <span>The Title</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 testimonial">
                        <img src="my-image-url.jpg">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> The content</p>
                        <span>The Title</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.testimonials {
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
.testimonial {
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    margin:10px 0 20px 0;
    padding:0 20px 20px 120px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.testimonial p i {
    color:#eb7022;
}
.testimonial span {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:130px;
}
.testimonial img {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin-right:120px;
    border-radius:6px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:16px;
}
```

You can also see it live [here](http://capicuaproyectos.com/mvd/).

Am I breaking something with these styles?
Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use `.row` with `.item`.

---

2. Apply `.active` class only to first item.

---

Instead of this:

```
<div class="row item active">
  <div class="col-md-6 testimonial">
    <img src="1.jpg">
    <p><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> The content</p>
    <span>The Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 testimonial">
    <img src="1.jpg">
    <p><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> The content</p>
    <span>The Title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use this:

```
<div class="item active">
  <div class="row>
    <div class="col-md-6 testimonial">
      <img src="1.jpg">
      <p><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> The content</p>
      <span>The Title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 testimonial">
      <img src="1.jpg">
      <p><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> The content</p>
      <span>The Title</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! The active class was on all of them because of copy+paste, but removing the row fixed it. Why was that?

Comment: I think it was caused by the fact that `.row` has negative margins (-15px), but I'm not sure. Generally you should not use any class combined with `.row`.